# Removing all the span tags with a specific class from the entire webpage using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I remove every `<span>` tag with the class "button-label"

`<span class="button-label"></span>`

along with its content from the entire webpage using javascript.

Answer (score 3):

can you try this :

```
$('span.button-label').remove()
```

this might also work :

```
$( "span" ).remove( ".button-label" );
```

check the docs [here](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)